# Progressbar in bash to visualize the time to wait

Tags: bash, programming

In a bash script sometimes you need the user to wait some seconds for a background process to finish.

I usually use for example:

```
sleep 10
```

How can I add a kind of progressbar to the script, so the user knows how long to wait?

I installed the command `bar` but I don't understand the manual.

Comment: [Bash FAQ 44](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/044)

Comment: I saw that, but it is only usable for copying files. In that case, I added another answer below

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
while true;do echo -n .;sleep 1;done &
sleep 10 # or do something else here
kill $!; trap 'kill $!' SIGTERM
echo done
```

this will start an infinite while loop that echos a spinner every second, executed in the background.

Instead of the `sleep 10` command run any command you want.

When that command finishes executing this will kill the last job running in the background (which is the infinite while loop)

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16348366/1069083

You can use various while loops instead, e.g. a spinner like this:

```
while :;do for s in / - \\ \|; do printf "\r$s";sleep 1;done;done
```

Answer (score 7):

This should be enough to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {001..100}; do
    sleep 1
    printf "\r $i"

done
```

Using the `\r` escape sequence returns the line to the start without a newline. This allows you to update the output without having hundreds of lines of output. By using this base, you could find a way to slowly print out an arrow such as `=>25%   ==>50%   ===>75%` instead of simply printing a number out. You could do this in a very basic way by using if-then logic to print out a specific number of ='s depending on the size of the number.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one using [cursor movements](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) that will rewrite the line in order to show a countdown:

```
c=5 # seconds to wait
REWRITE="\e[25D\e[1A\e[K"
echo "Starting..."
while [ $c -gt 0 ]; do 
    c=$((c-1))
    sleep 1
    echo -e "${REWRITE}$c"
done
echo -e "${REWRITE}Done."
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a way to add a progress bar to a timer with fixed sleeping time, you can also use a combination of echos and `pv`:

```
while true; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done | pv -s 10 -S -F '%t %p' > /dev/null
```

This produces a timer with progress bar:

```
0:00:02 [=====================>                                                      ] 30%
```

**Explanation**

- `while true; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done`
  infinitely prints a `.` once a second.
- `| pv -s 10 -S -F '%t %p'`
  pipes the output to [`pv`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html) that generates the progress bar

  - `-s SIZE, --size SIZE` defines the number of characters to expect
  - `-S, --stop-at-size` tells `pv` to stop after `SIZE` characters
  - `-F FORMAT, --format FORMAT` select what to print: elapsed time `%t` and progress bar `%p`
- `> /dev/null` prevents printing the outputs of our `echo` to the terminal (they are piped through by `pv`)
- select the timer duration with the `-s` flag (`-s 10` → 10 characters → 10 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to see the progress of a file-copy process, you can simply use

```
pv source_file > destination_file
```

or

```
rsync --progress source_file destination_file
```

instead of the `cp` command