# Verbose sleep command that displays pending time seconds/minutes?

Tags: sleep

sleep command can be used to introduce a delay. e.g. `sleep 5` will sleep for 5 seconds.

Is there any alternative/way/method that will display the pending seconds on the terminal?

output like

```
 resuming in 5 sec
```

the numeric values just countdowns on the same line of terminal.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92919/progressbar-in-bash-to-visualize-the-time-to-wait https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314512/how-to-determine-the-amount-of-time-left-in-a-sleep?

Answer (score 5):

A hacky approach using `pv`:

```
$ yes | pv -SeL1 -s 5 > /dev/null
ETA 0:00:04
```

Or:

```
$ yes | pv -SL1 -F 'Resuming in %e' -s 5 > /dev/null
Resuming in ETA 0:00:04
```

`pv` is normally used to give a progress bar for the I/O of some data stream. Here we're using the constant stream of the `yes` command, but rate-limiting it to 1 byte per second (`-L1`), and `S`topping after the output has reached a `s`ize of `5` bytes.

You can add more in there like the elapsed time, ETA as in clock time when it's expected to finish, or even a progress bar:

```
$ yes | pv -SpeL1 -s 5 > /dev/null
[===========>                                                  ] 20% ETA 0:00:04
```

Note that the duration won't be exactly 5 seconds (closer to 6 actually here with pv 1.6.6 in my tests).

Speaking of *progress bar*, you can also feed its output to `zenity` (graphical) or `diaglog`/`whiptail` for an even fancier display:

```
yes | pv -SnL1 -s 5 2>&1 > /dev/null | 
  zenity --progress --auto-close --no-cancel \
         --title 'Please wait...' --text 'Please wait...'
```

[image: zenity]

```
yes | pv -SnL1 -s 5 2>&1 > /dev/null |
  whiptail --gauge 'Please wait...' 5 20 0
```

[image: whiptail]

For a smoother progress, you can increase the rate to 10 bytes per second (and multiply the cut-off size by 10) while telling it to give you 10 updates per second:

```
yes | pv -SpeL10 -i0.1 -s 50 > /dev/null
```

```
yes | pv -SnL10 -i 0.1 -s 50 2>&1 > /dev/null |
  whiptail --gauge 'Please wait...' 6 20 0
```

Comment: On AppleM1, the first command is giving weird output. The ETA time is jumping around randomly, e.g. if initiated to sleep for 60 sec, the time shown 00:00:34 -> 00:00:45 -> 00:00:15 -> 00:00:10 .

Answer (score 1):

Running sleep 5 times?

```
for ((i=5;i>0;i--)); do printf '%s %s\r' "$i" 'seconds pending'; sleep 1; done; echo
```

The precision is quite good, there's just the overhead of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

- [elundmark/vsleep](https://gist.github.com/elundmark/59dcb9ada7263ee3ff68) written in bash.
- [sleep-v](https://github.com/tjhayasaka/sleep-v) written in ruby.